# Url Routing using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have:

```
<a href='News.aspx?Id=<%#Eval("Id") %>'>Read more</a>
```

and my querystring is setup like this:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Zaebancii where Id=@id", con);
SqlDataAdapter apd = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Page.Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString());
con.Open();
apd.Fill(ds, "Zaebancii");
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
FormView1.DataSource = ds;
FormView1.DataBind();
```

How can I url rewrite so the link would be `news/{Id}` e.g. `news/4/` shows the post of ID of 4 thank you

Comment: Just paste your question title into Google: https://www.google.com/search?q=URL+ROUTING+ASP.NET+WEBFORMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

place these codes in your global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}


public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
     routes.MapPageRoute("", "news/{id}", "~/News.aspx");
}
```

and you can get id like this;

```
RouteData.Values["id"];
```

Comment: <a href='<%"/news/" + Eval("Id").ToString() %>'>Read more</a>

Comment: im sorry but i may be a little stupid or thats because im newbie  RouteData.Values["id"]; where should i put this and the <a href='<%"/news/" + Eval("Id").ToString() %>'> its not working :/

Comment: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", RouteData.Values["id"].ToString());

Comment: what does not working mean? did you get blue screen? or codes began protesting for low wages?

Comment: <a href='<%# "/news/" + Eval("Id").ToString() %>'>Read more</a>  place the #

Answer (score 0):

You need to utilize Routing engine. In your global.asax, you may register below code, but in practice, utilize a separate class for that.

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute(routeName: "News", routeUrl: "news/{id}", physicalFile: "~/news.aspx", checkPhysicalUrlAccess: false, defaults: null, constraints: new RouteValueDictionary() { "id", "^\\d*$" });
```

To generate the link, you may use below for id = 1 for example:

```
string href = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(requestContext: null, name: "News", values = new RouteValueDictionary() { "id": "1" }).VirtualPath;
```